# How to display all sub folder names beginning with "I"

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is is possible to list all sub folder names beginning with the letter "I" and from this allow the user to select one?

Thanks
John.

Comment: Just wanting to use this on windows 7 pcs. Is that all the info you need?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you may traverse all subfolders with

`for /d /r D:\ %A in (*) DO CALL :SUB %A`

and in your subroutine you may process each foldername:

`:SUB
 SET B=%1
 IF NOT %B:~0,1%==%MatchLetter% GOTO :EOF
:DisplayFolderAndLetUserSelectIt
 ... insert appropriate code here
:EOF`

Untested, but it may give you an idea about where to start ... good luck ;-)

Comment: Thanks for that but I'm still a little unsure on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

SET "sourcedir=."
FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=:" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*" ^|findstr /b /i "N" ^|findstr /n "."'
  ) DO (
 ECHO %%a %%b
 SET "$%%a=%%b"
)
:cloop
SET "chosen="
SET /p "chosen=Your choice : "
IF NOT DEFINED chosen GOTO :EOF 
IF NOT DEFINED $%chosen% GOTO cloop
CALL SET "chosen=%%$%chosen%%%"
ECHO %chosen% was chosen

GOTO :EOF
```

This isn't bullet-proof, but should deal with user-input not designed to crash the routine. Simply pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> should exit with no choice made.